# Permission not working for External URL page DNN9

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have created page type External URL and assign some permission but page can be open by any users either not log in or non authorized users.

I want to provide some roles to access that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, DNN does not care about the permissions for external Urls.

The only way to go is adding a "normal" page and add something to that page that redirects to the external page, e.g. some JavaScript. You can use [Will Strohl's Content Injection module](https://github.com/hismightiness/dnnextensions/releases) for that.